# Need to expand table to fit hsize

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx, article

I need help expanding this table to the hsize of the page in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}


     \begin{adjustbox}{rotate=270}
             \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}     { 
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}c 
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}c }
      \hline
    [PW$_{11}$M(H$_2$O)O$_{39}$]$$^{q-}$ & O$_c$-P & O$_c$-M & O$_t$-M & O$_{a1}$-M & O$_{b2}$-M & O$_{a1}$-W & O$_{b2}$-W & O$_{a1}$-M-O$_{b2}$ \\ \hline
     [PW$_{11}$Mn(H$_2$O)O$_{39}$]$$^{4-}$       &     1.555    & 2.302        &  2.338       &  1.940          &    1.923        &  1.880          &  1.868          &   173.2         \\
     $[$PW$_{11}$Mn(H$_2$O)O$_{39}$$]$$$^{5-}$        &     1.558    & 2.377        &  2.303       &  2.137          &    2.048       &  1.829          &  1.833          &   168.0       \\
     $[$PW$_{11}$Fe(H$_2$O)O$_{39}$$]$$$^{4-}$       &     1.565    & 2.236        &  2.179       &  2.021          &    1.963        &  1.859          &  1.864          &   171.3      \\
     $[$PW$_{11}$Fe(H$_2$O)O$_{39}$$]$$$^{5-}$&     1.562    & 2.275        &  2.226       &  2.047          &    2.013        &  1.840          &  1.833          &   170.8      \\
    $[$PW$_{11}$Co(H$_2$O)O$_{39}$$]$$$^{4-}$ &   1.586        &   1.964      &   1.976      &   1.910         &  1.917          &  1.877          &     1.844       & 177.1            \\
     $[$PW$_{11}$Co(H$_2$O)O$_{39}$$]$$$^{5-}$ &   1.561      &2.248         &2.202         &2.072            &2.013            & 1.831           & 1.824           &  173.5           \\
     $[$PW$_{11}$Ru(H$_2$O)O$_{39}$$]$$$^{4-}$&   1.579      &      2.129   &    2.151     &  2.029          &    2.028        &    1.881        &    1.859        &        178.3      \\
     $[$PW$_{11}$Ru(H$_2$O)O$_{39}$$]$$$^{5-}$ &     1.576    &     2.149    &   2.166      &  2.066          &       2.031     &      1.849      &   1.831         &     177.4 \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{adjustbox} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code produces `! LaTeX Error: Environment tabularx undefined.`

Comment: if I add tabularx package it gives `! Missing $ inserted.`  please check that the example shows the issue that you want to show, which is not clear currently

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I'm pretty sure all instances of `$$$` should be `$$`.

Comment: If you're using `$$` to end one math expression and immediately start math expression, you might as well remove the `$$`.

Answer (score 5):

You really need to stop engaging in so much visual formatting. Do yourself a favor and take the time to learn how to use the `\ce` macro, which is provided by the `mhchem` package, to typeset chemical formulas. That way, you could replace `$[$PW$_{11}$Ru(H$_2$O)O$_{39}$$]$$$^{5-}$` with a much more manageable-looking `\ce{[PW11 Ru(H2O)O39]^{5-}}`, etc.

Aside: For the table at hand, I recommend using a `sidewaystable` environment and a `tabular*` environment (with a target width of `\textwidth`) rather than a `tabularx` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.
\usepackage{mhchem}   % for '\ce' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c} }
\toprule
\ce{[PW11Mn(H2O)O39]^{q-}} & O$_c$-P & O$_c$-M & O$_t$-M & O$_{a1}$-M & O$_{b2}$-M & O$_{a1}$-W & O$_{b2}$-W & O$_{a1}$-M-O$_{b2}$ \\ 
\midrule
\ce{[PW11Mn(H2O)O39]^{4-}} & 1.555 & 2.302 & 2.338 & 1.940 & 1.923 & 1.880 & 1.868 & 173.2\\
\ce{[PW11Mn(H2O)O39]^{5-}} & 1.558 & 2.377 & 2.303 & 2.137 & 2.048 & 1.829 & 1.833 & 168.0\\ \addlinespace
\ce{[PW11Fe(H2O)O39]^{4-}} & 1.565 & 2.236 & 2.179 & 2.021 & 1.963 & 1.859 & 1.864 & 171.3\\
\ce{[PW11Fe(H2O)O39]^{5-}} & 1.562 & 2.275 & 2.226 & 2.047 & 2.013 & 1.840 & 1.833 & 170.8\\ \addlinespace
\ce{[PW11Co(H2O)O39]^{4-}} & 1.586 & 1.964 & 1.976 & 1.910 & 1.917 & 1.877 & 1.844 & 177.1\\
\ce{[PW11Co(H2O)O39]^{5-}} & 1.561 & 2.248 & 2.202 & 2.072 & 2.013 & 1.831 & 1.824 & 173.5\\ \addlinespace
\ce{[PW11Ru(H2O)O39]^{4-}} & 1.579 & 2.129 & 2.151 & 2.029 & 2.028 & 1.881 & 1.859 & 178.3\\
\ce{[PW11Ru(H2O)O39]^{5-}} & 1.576 & 2.149 & 2.166 & 2.066 & 2.031 & 1.849 & 1.831 & 177.4\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```